# How to use jQuery toggle method dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

In my project, there are so many jQuery `toggle`s needed for changing text and icons. Now I’m doing that using:

```
$("#id1").click(function () {
  //Code to toggle display and change icon and text
});

$("#id2").click(function () {
  //Same Code to toggle display and change icon and text as above except change in id
});
```

The problem is that I got so many to toggle, the code is quite long but all I change for each one is the id. So I was wondering if there is any way to make this simple.

Below is a sample pic. I got so many more in single page.

[image: Checkboxes]

Comment: can you post working fiddle?

Comment: you need to learn when we Exactly use. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle 
either
 please post fiddle.

Comment: Please refer this link also [link]('https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse_togglebtn&stacked=h')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1. How to run the same action on multiple elements
2. How to know which element you've clicked so that you can run a *relevant* action on it.  (most of the existing answers skip this part).

The first is to use a class for each of the elements you want to click, rather than wire up via an id.  You can use a selector similar to `[id^=id]` but it's just cleaner to use a class.

```
<div id="id1" class="toggler">...
```

which allows you to:

```
$(".toggler").click(function() ...
```

the second is it associate the clickable with the item you want to toggle.  There are many ways to do this, my preferred option is to associate them with `data-` attributes, eg:

```
<div class="togger" data-toggle="#toggle1">...
```

which allows you to:

```
$(".toggler").click(function() {
    $($(this).data("toggle")).toggle();
});
```

The key here is that `this` is the element being clicked, so you can do anything else with `this` such as show/hide an icon inside or change colour.

Example:

```js
$(".toggler").click(function() {
  $($(this).data("toggle")).toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
.toggler { cursor: pointer }
.toggled { background-color: green }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggler" data-toggle="#t1">T1</div>
<div class="toggler" data-toggle="#t2">T2</div>
<div class="toggler" data-toggle="#t3">T3</div>

<hr/>

<div id="t1" style='display:none;'>T1 content</div>
<div id="t2" style='display:none;'>T2 content</div>
<div id="t3" style='display:none;'>T3 content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh,Can you use a `class` instead of `id`?

```html
<ul>
  <li class="idx">A</li>
  <li class="idx">B</li>
  <li class="idx">C</li>
</ul>
```

```
$(".idx").click(function(e){
   //Code to toggle display and change icon and text
  let target = e.target;
  //You can do all what you want just base on the `target`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the queries in an array, and iterate over them to perform the same JQuery operation on all of them

```js
let ids = ["#id1", "#id2", "#id3", "#randomID"]

ids.forEach((id) => {
  console.log($(id).html())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="id1">A</li>
  <li id="id2">B</li>
  <li id="id3">C</li>
  <li id="randomID">D</li>
</ul>
```

Or (If like your example) and all of the id's are actually `id1, id2, id3, ...` etc.

```js
let id = "id";
let n = 3; //amount of id's

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  console.log($("#" + id + i).html())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="id1">A</li>
  <li id="id2">B</li>
  <li id="id3">C</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below code.

```js
var num = $("#myList").find("li").length;
  console.log(num)
for(i=0;i<num;i++){
$("#id"+ i).click(function(e){
  let target = e.target;
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li id="id1">A</li>
  <li id="id2">B</li>
  <li id="id3">C</li>
</ul>
```